# How to using pipe in loop, is mine correct?

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork, posix

I want to know if my usage of pipe is correct, this code is in the fork() child process, and pfd is pipe pointer:

```
char buf[1024];
while(1){
    signal(SIGUSR1, OnSigUsr1);
    sleep(10000);
    if(get==1){
        get=0;
        close(pfd[1]);
        read(pfd[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
        close(pfd[0]);
    }
}
```

another episode of code in the parent code:

```
char buffer[1024];
/*put something in buffer*/
close(pfd[0]);
if(write(pfd[1], buffer, strlen(buffer))==-1){
     printf("error write\n");
};
close(pfd[1]);
kill(fpid,SIGUSR1);
```

My problem is the buffer can be written and get from fork() for only one time, next time it can't be written in pipe again and return `error write`. I wonder if I made it some place wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must 
include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful 
to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is get initialized to ?  What is the definition of OnSigUsr1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of pipe, the write blocks if pipe is full.

Note that the data written into the write-end of pipe is buffered in kernel until it is read from the read-end of the pipe.

`child :` The pfd[1] can be closed in child as it is not used in child. But, it is not required to close pfd[0] if it shall be used by child subsequently.

`parent :` Similarly, the pfd[0] can be closed in parent as it is not used in parent. But, it is not required to close pfd[1] if it shall be used by parent subsequently.

Comment: Thank you, you are right! It works. Do you know what's the difference?

Comment: For the benefit of everyone, can you share the changes done.

Comment: just comment the close pfd[0] in child and close pfd[1] in parent. Do i need to post it again? The original code is extremely long.

Answer (score 1):

You can only write data to an open file descriptor.  The parent executes `close(pfd[1]);` after writing the buffer, and the child executes `close(pfd[0]);` after reading the buffer.  Don't close a file descriptor if you will use it again, but close all open file descriptors before your program exits.

Comment: "close all open file descriptors before your program exits": Not necessary. All file descriptors are automatically closed on program exit: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_exit.html

Comment: @jforberg,  When a program fails to clean up after itself it is sloppy code.  you should not get in the habit of having the OS cleanup after your program.   Amongst other reasons, not every application is running on an OS.

Comment: Modern, full featured operating systems clean up after sloppy code to be user friendly(If a programmer writes sloppy code, it won't bring down the system), but not all operating systems do, which is why you should never write sloppy code.